# Finding the end date from asynchronous starting but consecutive running date ranges

Tags: postgresql, date, theory

I need to help with a database model and and efficient calculation method of the last end date.

The ranges have a start date but will wait to start until the currently active ranges have ended. Changing the length or start of one range should cascade to the waiting ranges and push them back. But they can never start before their start date.

The database mock here is just to explain the problem and doesn't need to be followed as long as it works properly.

```
| id | start | length | 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  1 |    03 |      2 |         ------                                 |
|  2 |    06 |      2 |                     ------                     |
```

I am aware that I can brute force the answer to get the last date. But I'm looking for a more efficient solution as there are many ranges and the end date needs to read often.

Also is this something that's possible to calculate in a PostgreSQL query? Or maybe keep end date fields up to date with triggers?

#### Examples

Here range 2 starts on `04` but can't be used until after range 1 finishes.

```
| id | start | length | 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  1 |    02 |      5 |     ------------------                         |
|  2 |    04 |      5 |                         ------------------     |
```

If we update the range 1, range 2 should move up with it.

```
| id | start | length | 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  1 |    02 |      4 |     --------------                             |
|  2 |    04 |      5 |                     ------------------         |
```

But range 2 shouldn't move past its start date.

```
| id | start | length | 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  1 |    02 |      1 |     --                                         |
|  2 |    04 |      5 |             ------------------                 |
```

If you just take the latest start date and add its duration you will get the wrong answer.

```
| id | start | length | 01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  10  11  12 |
|  1 |    04 |      5 |             ------------------                 |
|  2 |    05 |      2 |                                 ------         |

Get: 7
Expected: 10
```

Comment: How (often/many) are the ranges inserted, updated and deleted? Do modifications mostly or only at the end, or anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to calculate this in a query, but as you figured it will need to read *all* ranges which is hardly efficient unless you know there won't be many or are ok with doing some arbitrary cutoff that doesn't consider older delays. So yes, some auxiliary structures with derived values will be required. How to choose them (to allow both efficient queries and efficient updates or at least a reasonable tradeoff) depends on the answers to my first comment.

Comment: Records will be inserted several times a day, updated once in a while and almost never deleted. Reading will happen many times in a day. Getting the end date needs to be fairly quick as its one the most common values I use. There's currently ~2000 records but this continues to grow. Since it more reading than writing would saving a calculated value be ideal? Updating it after updates.